# internal storage in different threads

Tags: android, multithreading

Good day, I have one theoretical question. I have an application that run some threads. One of the thread download xml file to local storage, have other threads access to this file?

Comment: Your whole application and everything inside it has access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All threads will have access, but the data can be currupted or not complete, if you don't **synchronize** access to it. There is a number of options. 
Refer to [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).